# Display content below specific SPAN

Tags: html, css

I have following code:

```
<div>
  <span class="red">TEXT 1</span>
  <span class="blue">TEXT 2</span>
  <span class="yellow">TEXT 3</span>
</div>
```

My result is just pure line

```
TEXT1 TEXT2 TEXT3
```

I would like to add some text exactly below 2-nd span (TEXT2) without any changes to following element.

So end result must be something like that

```
TEXT1 TEXT2 TEXT3
      HELLO WORLD APP
```

How should I do that?

I tried to set display: block for TEXT 2 but it did not really work as I expected.

Thanks!

Comment: are you using bootstrap or another framework or is this a general question?

Comment: no, just own css.

Comment: I've some changed my answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute positioning would be one option:

```css
.blue { position: relative; }
.blue span { position: absolute; top: 1em; left: 0; white-space: pre; }
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="red">TEXT 1</span>
  <span class="blue">TEXT 2 <span>HELLO WORLD APP</span></span>
  <span class="yellow">TEXT 3</span>
</div>
```

Note however that if the middle span (TEXT 2) is too close to the right corner of the viewport, the content in the inner span might get cut of. Depends on the specific scenario whether that’s a dealbreaker or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more solution using pure CSS and adding a title as span attribute.

Defined `::before` pseudo element, positioned absolutely and containing a data attribute value.

```css
.blue::before{
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="red">TEXT 1</span>
  <span class="blue" data-text="HELLO WORLD APP">TEXT 2</span>
  <span class="yellow">TEXT 3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.hello {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="red">TEXT 1</span>
  <span class="blue">
    TEXT 2
    <span class="hello">HELLO WORLD APP</span>
  </span>
  <span class="yellow">TEXT 3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not make this a SO snippet?

Comment: No reason, you're right, should've used the embedded, new to answering